# Mat Expansion Panel opens by default buggy

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nested, angular-material

i've got a problem with the mat expansion panel. I have nested mat expansion panels which are controlled by a "panel control" (view code) to allow multiple opened mat expansion panels.

Everyone works fine except that the first mat expansion panel opens by default and is shown buggy. After I close the panel and open in it up again, everything works fine.

HTML:

```
 <mat-accordion id="headacc" multi="true" *ngFor="let account of accounts; let i = index;">
              <mat-expansion-panel id="headexp1" (opened)="onPanelOpen((i+1))" (closed)="onPanelClosed()" [expanded]="false">

                <mat-expansion-panel-header id="header">
                  *some irrelevant code*
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                <mat-accordion id="subacc">

                  <mat-expansion-panel id="subexp" multi="true"
                    *ngFor="let transaction of transactions[i]; let j = index;"
                    (opened)="onChildPanelOpen((i+1), (j+1))" [expanded]="false">

                    <mat-expansion-panel-header id="subheader">
                      *some irrelevant code*
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    *some irrelevant code*
                  </mat-expansion-panel>
                </mat-accordion>
              </mat-expansion-panel>
            </mat-accordion>
```

Typescript:

```
panels = [0, 1, 2];
childPanels = [11, 22, 33];
selectedPanel = 0;
childopened = false;

onPanelOpen(x: number) {
    console.log(`Panel ${x} opened.${this}`);
    this.childopened = true;
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
  }

  onPanelClosed(x: number) {
    this.childopened = false;
  }

  onChildPanelOpen(x: number, y: number) {
    console.log(`Panel ${x} opened, Child Panel ${y} opened.`);
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
  }
```

After loading the page it looks like that:
[Buggy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjony.png)

Does anyone know if this a bug or if I did something wrong?

EDIT: I created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjwihs

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: Yeah sure, here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jjwihs

Comment: The stackblitz you created doesn't have that bug you described

Comment: Check here https://imgur.com/a/gyTj3iV

Comment: Well, I'm using Firefox on Mac and it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/1ndXnHR
It seems to be a problem with mac there, hmm... as Gerald from the Witcher would say.

Comment: Well, i won't say with mac.. I'd say with Firefox. Can you check with other browsers?

Comment: It works with firefox on windows but not on mac. Safari or Chrome has no problems there.